# Rspec remove activerecord column named method for testing behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my application. If the `users` table has `foo` column, which causes activerecord to add `foo` named instance method to `User` class, `MyEngine.bar` call will return `'xyz'`.
And if the that column isn't defined, `MyEngine.bar` call will return `'abc'`. This behavior change is caused by this code in `bar` method call: `current_user.respond_to?(:foo)`

How i go about testing this behavior?

The test flow I have in mind looks like this:

```
it "does something" do
  user = FactoryBot.create(:user, foo: "something")
  sign_in(user)
  expect(MyEngine.bar).to eq "xyz"
  # remove foo here to test how user responds when it's missing
  expect(MyEngine.bar).to eq "abc"
end
```

I want to be able to remove the `foo` column temporarily for testing purposes.

Comment: Is the method originally in the class you are trying to test, or you want to add the method dynamically just for testing. Need this info to prepare something for you.

Comment: It's in the class and I want to temporarily remove it.  It should return once the spec example finishes.

Comment: Also in your question there is a confusion, you are saying you want to test what happens if some column is not defined. Which should be something like: `MyEngine.first.bar` which makes bar an instance method. While you have put `MyEngine.bar` which makes `bar` a class method. Also note that as of my knowledge, rails don't define a method, it uses the cllbacks of ruby which are triggered if a method is missing and acts accordingly. I will add answer as per your code, ignoring the confusion. Which means you want to remove a class method named `bar` from `MyEngine`. We can make any updates later.

Comment: Same is true for class methods added by rails, they are not defined hardcoded(as far as i can tell), i tried the method i was thinking of to solve your problem, that worked on normal class method which we define with `def self.bar` syntax, but it didn't work for rails added class methods to models like `all` and `count`. I have to dig deeper to figure out how to remove these. But i need confirmation what you actually want, remove these ones or the instance methods like user.first.name ones.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. When `MyEngine.bar` executes, it runs `current_user` to get the signed in user.  `bar` behaves differently depending on the answer to `current_user.respond_to?(:foo)`. `foo` is an active record attribute and `user` models are free to include this attribute or not.

Comment: Last question(hopefully), is the same instance of `user` is used as `current_user` or `current_user ` is a different instance which is populated with another find_by call? If it is same instance as `user` solution can be simpler, if not solution will be a little tricky.

Comment: Or should I say, can we stub/control the `current_user` method? I think we should be able to, assuming that i will add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion in comments section, assuming you can stub/control the `current_user` what i will do is:

```
it "does something" do
  user = FactoryBot.create(:user, foo: "something")
  sign_in(user)
  expect(MyEngine.bar).to eq "xyz"

  # here we remove foo method for only this instance of user
  user.singleton_class.class_eval {undef :foo}
  # Now stub call to current_user, of-course this line 
  # will adapt your code in MyEngine and how it calls current_user
  # also note expect, you may use allow here instead, but i would prefer expect
  expect(MyEngine).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
  expect(MyEngine.bar).to eq "abc"
  # You will get back foo method on any new user instances:
  # user = User.find(user.id)
end
```

This approach limits the consequences very much. Should solve your problem as per my understanding.